# Send UDP packets to a node in another network

Tags: networking, udp, ip, portforwarding, packets

I'm trying to send UPD packets from node A to node B, both are connected to internet through different routers. 
I am able to send (and receive) UDP packets between them when they connected on the same network by giving the local destination ip adddress (192.168.*.*) and port number.

Now I'm finding the dynamic ip address of node B using www.whatismyip.com and consider it as w.x.y.z 
When I send the packets from A to this destination, I'm unable to receive them at B. I've also setup port forwarding on both the routers.

This is completely new to me. Is there is something else that needs to be done when I want to send packets to a node connected on another network? Please help!!

Comment: not sure what to do with this - it's clearly off topic here because it's not a programming question as such, but nor does it match the criteria for serverfault

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest something to check:

- Port Forwarding in both the router are configured for the UDP protocol?
- If you ping the remote address w.x.y.z, you receive a response? (check if the routers are configured to do so)
- Verify also if there are firewall that block the UDP packet that arrives from the Internet (on the routers or on the target machine).

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you can not receive them at B is because NAT will filter all the messages if you haven't build a connection in the netfilter's table. The way to solve the problem is to use a port mapping like UPNP or NAT-PMP. In this way, the destination node's specific port will receive any message from WLAN and send it to this node. But this needs your router support these protocols, if not, maybe you need to use ICE as a realy server to realize it.