# Forward UDP packets to an external network

Tags: windows, networking, udp, port, portforwarding

There's a stream of UDP data that I can recognize on my computer coming in from wireshark. I'd like to forward this data to different network (for example, from NY to LA). What's the fastest way (in terms of latency) to do this?

After reading into port forwarding and UPnP I haven't had anything working yet. I've managed to get a golang program that can transfer data across a local network, but this needs to be to an outside one.

I think the best way is to grab my IP through https://www.whatismyip.com/, then allow a client to connect to it. From there, transfer these UDP packets over. Is there a specific language/term that I should be using here to implement this?

I'd like to be able to make it runnable in an application, but even a command line would work. The only limitation is that it has to be through Windows, so I can't use something like iptables.

---

These packets come in at a rate of 60 packets/second. Would netcat be able to forward all of this data?

**Edit**: Related to [Send UDP packets to a node in another network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28895574/send-udp-packets-to-a-node-in-another-network?rq=1) from 5 years ago, but the question didn't get a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. What do you mean "forward this data to different network "? Whether the source node and destination node are behind a router or have a public IP address will influence how to realize it.

Let's think about the circumstance that both of the nodes are behind a router, which means NAT works and translate their IP. In this example, you need to do the following things.

1. A public IP address of destination node must be known if you want to send a message to it
2. A port mapping in destination node so that the message can be received by it, that is where Upnp and NAT-PMP works.
3. If you want it to be simple, you can use ICE, but this will need a central server as a relay.

Comment: I meant using public IP addresses. I managed to get data transfer working from within the same router. What would I need to do to allow it to be sent out?

Comment: If both of the sides use  a public IP address, you can use the IP address to send and receive, if not, following my answer 1-3.